# How to delete a record using a Foreign Key

Tags: t-sql

I want to delete all the records from QryCriteria where the CfgQryCriteriaId is the CfgQryCriteriaId from CfgQryCriteria
WHERE Criteria = 'PolicyAdministration.MDSL.Terms.LockInDate'

Below is what i have so far,can someone be of assistance?

```
 BEGIN TRY
 BEGIN TRANSACTION CFG 
     DELETE FROM QryCriteria 

     WHERE CfgQryCriteriaId  = 'PolicyAdministration.MDSL.Terms.LockInDate'

 END TRY

 BEGIN CATCH
 if(@@TRANCOUNT >0)

 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION CFG 

 END CATCH
```

Comment: Please add a table definition, including any keys and constraints, especially the Foreign Key.  If the Foreign Key relates to another table, include its definition also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to use a subquery to get all of the appropriate `CfgQryCriteria` values:

```
delete from QryCriteria
  where CfgQryCriteriaId in (
    select COC.CfgQryCriteriaId from CfgQryCriteria as COC where COC.Criteria = 'PolicyAdministration.MDSL.Terms.LockInDate' );
```

A similar query could be constructed using `where exists` and a correlated subquery. A third choice would be deleting from an `inner join` between the two tables.